# Multiple ArrayLists with different sizes to be sent from servlet to JSP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, arraylist

I have multiple ArrayLists containing different number of items. 
The first one is

```
ArrayList items = ["fruits", "flowers"]; 

ArrayList fruits = ["apple", "banana"]; 
ArrayList flowers = ["rose", "lily","lotus"];
```

I have to send these to another JSP file. I also have to use AJAX as these arraylists will be populating two dropdowns with Parent child relationship. 1st dropdown will have 'fruits' and 'flowers' as options, the other depending on the 1st will be populated either by fruit name or flower name. I am also unable to use jQuery because of some conflict issues.

Can anybody help me pass those arraylists to jsp. Is a 2D JSON possible with different lengths for each column? Is there another better way than using ArrayLists and JSON?

Comment: user5673235 I just edited the question in order to improve the format,but it would be would if you check the syntax of your code. It seems to me there is a missing `[` in the second line

Comment: thanks.. yeah..sorry about the missing [.. but thats just for reference